# Admin router redirects to dashboard

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, custom, routing

I am trying to create a custom controller in admin side.

My config file as below:

```
<admin>
        <routers>
            <salesref>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Ucs_Order</module>
                    <frontName>salesref</frontName>
                </args>
            </salesref>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

My Controller located in below:

`app\code\local\Ucs\Order\controllers\Adminhtml\ReferenceController.php`

Content of my controller as below,

```
<?php

class Ucs_Order_Adminhtml_ReferenceController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo 'Test';
        die;

    }
}
```

Then I am trying to access the URL as below,

`http://192.168.100.68/magento/index.php/salesref/adminhtml_reference/index`

But It automatically redirects to dashboard,

Whats the problem with my code?

Comment: Have applied [SUPEE-6788](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788) security patch on your Magento?

Comment: @JayeshPatel No. All other extension I used is redirecting properly

Comment: Please try to disabled `Add Secret Key to URLs` setting to `No` in `Admin > System > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Security (tab)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you had secrete settings enabled for Admin URl, it will redirect you to dashboard when you try to run URL without it.

Check settings in admin

```
Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Advanced (Bottom Left) -> Admin -> Security(Tab) -> Check Field  "Add Secret Key to URLs"
```

If you want to access URL without secret key try to set value No and check.

Comment: Cheers man.. Problem solved. How can I generate a key for my custom URL?

Comment: call URL as Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("salesref/reference/index"); and you will get it with key itself

Comment: no it will generate URL for backend

Comment: Got it.. Did a silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

#### It's not an answer on your question. Just recommendation.

Magento policy do not recommend to use

```
<use>admin</use>
```

when you'd like to create admin controller. Look how it achieved in `Mage_ImportExport`.

If you search throw your `app/code` folder and find more than 1 it's usage of `<use>admin</use>` - it's abnormal